# Writing custom test scripts

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm interested in writing some custom test scripts for btc core. Is there any documentation on the test suite anywhere? I did find [this link](http://diyhpl.us/wiki/transcripts/scalingbitcoin/tel-aviv-2019/edgedevplusplus/bitcoin-core-functional-test-framework/).

Comment: Could you be more specific what you want to do? What type of test are you talking about? [Functional tests](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/test/functional#writing-functional-tests), [unit tests](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/test#adding-test-cases), [fuzz tests](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/fuzzing.md), [benchmarks](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/benchmarking.md), or something else?

Comment: Functional tests